# Geometric meaning of the projection from the sphere to the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, visualization

In this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59275/664) from Mathematica.SE to a question regarding a video of the Möbius transformations, a function is defined as follows.

Given $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the output of the function is 
$$
\bigg(\frac{r(1+x_3)}{1+x_3-y_3}\cos(\theta+\pi)+x_1,
\frac{r(1+x_3)}{1+x_3-y_3}\sin(\theta+\pi)+x_2,0\bigg)
$$
where
$$
r:=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2},\quad
\theta:=\arctan\frac{x_2-y_2}{x_1-y_1}.
$$

Would anybody explain why this is a "projection from the sphere to the (complex) plane"? What does the pair of points $x$ and $y$ mean?

Comment: The principal reference is to sterographic projection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinate of the center of the sphere $S$ is given by $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and the radius of the sphere is $1$. This makes sense since the output of the function is of the form $(R\cos\psi+x_1,R\sin\psi+x_2,0)$, which implies that $x_1,x_2$ are the first two coordinates of the center of the sphere.

On the other hand, $y=(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ is the coordinate of a point on the sphere. The output of the function gives the coordinate of the "sterographic projection" of $y$ (the intersection of the line (which goes through $y$ and the north pole of the sphere) with the complex plane). When $x=(0,0,0),$ the function coincides with [the one defined in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection#Definition).

---

One needs to be careful of the definition $\theta$ since in Mathematica, `ArcTan[x,y]` is different from the function $\arctan\frac{y}{x}$. For instance one has in Mathematica `ArcTan[1,1]`=$\frac{\pi}{4}$ and `ArcTan[-1,-1]`=$\frac{-3\pi}{4}$. This is why $\theta+\pi$ instead of $\theta$ is used in the output of the function. For the sake of a *function*, one could define $\theta$ as the angle of the vector $(y_1-x_1,y_2-x_2,0)$ with the $X_1$-axis and replace $\theta+\pi$ with $\theta$ in the output of the function.

Comment: One might need to be careful with the $\theta$ part of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume for the moment that $x$ and $y$ are both supposed to be points ON the unit sphere. Then the big formula looks like

$$
(x_1, x_2, 0) + stuff
$$
so it represents a vertical projection of the point $x$, offset by some amount. The offset is in the direction of the ray from $x$ to $y$ (as seen from above (i.e., from a point infinitely far out along the $z$-axis). From the formula, it looks as if what's being done is something LIKE a stereographic projection from $x$: roughly: take a ray from $x$ through $y$, and see where it hits the $z = 0$ plane.

That's not QUITE right, because the denominator isn't zero when $x$ and $y$ have the same third coord, but rather when those coords differ by $1$. So maybe it's more like this:

Take points $x$ and $y$. Raise $x$ up by one in the third coordinate. Draw a ray from this new location through $y$, and see where it hits the $z = 0$ plane.